# Add field to a Mongo document using a string for its name

Tags: c#, mongodb, bson

I'd like to create a new field on an existing document. I'm using the following line to get all the documents out of the database into POCOs:

```
var collection = _database.GetCollection<Address>(collectionName);
```

I then make some changes to each and save them back into the database using this line:

```
collection.ReplaceOne(
 filter: new BsonDocument("_id", a.id),
 options: new UpdateOptions { IsUpsert = true },
 replacement: a);
```

That all works nicely.

To add a field, I've tried the following:

```
a.ToBsonDocument().Add("RainfallMM", rainfallMM);
```

But it doesn't make it to the database. Is there a trick to it?

Comment: did you add that field to Address model?

Comment: Hi BOR, no I haven't added it to the Address model. I'm looking to add the field dynamically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked you in comment did you add new property to address model and you said you didn't and you want to add it dynamically. Trick here is you initialize your collection as collection of addresses and mongo ignores all properties that are not part of address model by default.

If you want to add it dynamically you need to change how you start your collection to:

```
var collection = _database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("addresses");
```

Now your collection is not tied to address model and you can work with it as you wish. Everything is BSON document now!

For example you can do this:

```
var inserted = MongoCollection.Find(x => true).FirstOrDefault();
inserted.Add(new BsonElement("RainfallMM", rainfallMM);
MongoCollection.ReplaceOne(new BsonDocument("_id", inserted["_id"]), inserted);
```

PS there are some other workarounds and if this one you don't like I can show you the rest =)

Hope it helps! Cheers!

Comment: Superbly explained. Thanks BOR

Comment: Feel free to add your other workarounds as answers too

Answer (score 2):

As @Fidel asked me to I will try to briefly summarize other solutions. The problem in accepted answer is that while it works it loses it's connection to Address model and OP is stuck with working with BSON documents.

IMO working with plain BSON documents is pain.

If he ever wishes to change back to initializing collection as collection of Addresses and tries to get anything from db he will encounter an error saying something like:

> Missing serialization information for rainfallMM

He can fix that by including tag above his Address class like this:

```
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
public class Address 
{
    ...fluff and stuff...
}
```

Problem now is if he is not careful he can lose all his info in dynamically added properties.

Other problem is if he adds another property dynamically. Now he has to remember there are 2 properties which are not in model and the hell breaks loose.

Weather he likes it or not, to make his life easier he will probably have to modify Address model. There are 2 approaches and their official documentation is great (I think), so I will just link it here:

http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.4/examples/mixing_static_and_dynamic/

IF you ask me which one is better I will honestly tell you it depends on you. From documentation you will see that if you use an extra BSON document property you don't have to worry about naming your extra properties.

That would be all I can think of now! 
Hope it helps you!

Comment: Once again a great answer. Particularly the reference to the "Mixing Static and Dynamic" article. That is precisely what I'm trying to do. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
a.Add({"RainfallMM", rainfallMM});
```